# Proof that a set of vectors spans a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I want to prove that the vectors $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}7\\8\\0\end{bmatrix}$ span $\{(x,y,0)\le\mathbb{R}^3\}$.

Suppose $\alpha\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+\beta\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+\delta\begin{bmatrix}7\\8\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\0\end{bmatrix}$. Then we obtain the following simultaneous equations:

1. $\alpha+\gamma+7\delta=x$
2. $\beta+\gamma+8\delta=y$

I'm not sure how to finish the proof though

Comment: $\beta$ shouldn't appear in 1. When you fix that it is easy to find a solution with $\gamma = \delta = 0$.

Comment: Hint: the last two vectors are superfluous. Can you solve it without these?

Comment: I've edited this now - why do we need to have $\gamma=\delta=0$?

Comment: You don't need $\gamma =\delta = 0$, but when you've gained some more familiarity with thus subject, it may become obvious to you that the third and fourth vectors are in the span of the first two vectors and so you can ignore them when trying to work out what the span of all four vectors is.

Answer (score 3):

Let the first two vectors be $a,b$ respectively. Then $a+b$  is the third vector and $7a+8b$ is the fourth vector. Thus, the vectors given span the space spanned by $a$ and $b$, which is precisely $\{(x,y,0) \mid x,y\in\mathbb R\}$.

---

More formally, if $\{a_1,\ldots, a_m\}$ is linearly independent and $\{a_1,\ldots,a_m, b\}$ is linearly dependent, then
$$ \mathrm{span}(a_1,\ldots,a_m) = \mathrm{span}(a_1,\ldots,a_m,b). $$
This implies $\mathrm{span}(a,b) = \mathrm{span}(a,b,c) =\mathrm{span}(a,b,d)$. Suffices to show
$$\mathrm{span}(a,b,c,d) = \mathrm{span}(\mathrm{span}(a,b,c)+\mathrm{span}(a,b,d)) $$
and the result follows.

---

---

As for your approach, it also works. The goal is to verify that given $x,y\in\mathbb R$
$$ \begin{cases} \alpha + 0\beta + \gamma + 7\delta = x \\ 0\alpha + \beta + \gamma + 8\delta = y \end{cases} $$
has a solution. This is true by [Kronecker-Capelli](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Kronecker-Capelli_theorem).

Comment: How did you get from the point "...is the fourth vector" to "Thus the vectors span the space"?

Comment: Last statement needs correction: span$\{e_1,e_2\}\ne $span $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, where $e_1=(1,0,0)^T\in \mathbb R^3$ etc.

Comment: @Koro agreed, fixed now, I think

Answer (score 1):

Here is basically a more abstract rewriting of @Alvin Lepik's excellent answer, but I wish to add a few remarks that I hope are useful to solve other problems.

First of all, if $A$ is a (possibly infinite) subset of vectors of $V={\mathbb R}^n$, then $span(A)$ is the subspace generated by $A$, that is the set of all possible finite linear combinations of some vectors of $A$. Equivalently, $span(A)$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ containing $A$. By convention, $span(\emptyset)=\{0\}$.

Then, it is clear (prove it if it is not) that

1. $A\subset span(A)$
2. if $A\subset B$, then $span(A)\subset span(B)$
3. $A$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $V=span(V)$.

Now, let $v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $v_3=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$, and $v_4=\begin{bmatrix}7\\8\\0\end{bmatrix}$, $A=\{v_1,v_2\}$, $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ and $W=\{\; (x,y,0)\; |\; x,y\in \mathbb R\; \}$.

Clearly, $W$ is a vector space and $(x,y,0)=xv_1+yv_2$, so $W=span(A)$. Now, since $A\subset B\subset W$, we get

$$span(A)\subset span(B) \subset span(W)$$

which means that $W=span(B)$.